# Как применять изолированные блоки try/catch в методах и сервисах с бизнес-логикой?

Tags: исключения, любой-язык, чистый-код

Роберт Мартин в книге "Чистый код" писал:

> Изолируйте блоки try/catch Блоки try/catch выглядят весьма уродливо.
> Они запутывают структуру кода и смешивают обработку ошибок с
> нормальной обработкой. По этой причине тела блоков try и catch
> рекомендуется выделять в отдельные функции

Я согласен, так чище, но возникает несколько вопросов как организовывать свой код в некоторых моментах.

Допустим у меня есть контроллер, который обрабатывает данные и вызывает методы сервиса, который, в свою очередь, занимается бизнес-логикой.

Например код из книги:

```
public void delete(Page page) {
   try {
       deletePageAndAllReferences(page);
   } catch (Exception e) {
           logError(e);
   }
}
```

В случае с `try/catch` в контроллере, если операция произошла не успешно, то я бы вернул ответ сервера, например "Удаление объекта не удалось, попробуйте ещё раз". А в текущем варианте, т.к. метод `delete` сам по себе `void`, то что делать? Т.е. я в контроллере я вызову `delete`, он запнётся и дальше что?

Предположим я буду возвращать в методе статус выполнения метода `delete`. Но это уже становится нелогично, потому что метод уже не занимается одним каким-то делом, но уже и ещё что-то делает (формирует данные для результата).  Получается теперь, что **все** методы `void`, в которых  `try/catch` должны возвращать результат данной операции?

Другой момент: если нужно вернуть список пользователей из БД по некому условию и операция происходит неудачно, то в `catch` нужно записывать пустой массив и возвращать его? Разве не должно в `catch` быть что-то типа обработки ошибкив в виде её логирования и информирования пользователя, что "Извините, но что-то пошло не так"? Или вариант возврата пустого массива в таком случае вполне приемлемый?

В общем, меня одновременно и воодушевляет такой подход и запутывает. Что делать в случае, которые описал выше? Какие нюансы нужно учитывать при таком подходе? Например нужно что-то вернуть или "залогировать и забить"? Когда это правильно применять и как?

Comment: *"Разве не должно в catch быть что-то типа обработки ошибкив в виде её логирования и информирования пользователя, что "Извините, но что-то пошло не так"?"* Вопрос. Сколько таких блоков ты планируешь написать в коде среднего приложения?

Comment: Вам нужно ловить ошибку на том уровне, на котором вы можете ее правильно\удобно обработать. В ваших примерах, все же лучше ловить ошибки в контроллерах.

Comment: @Ипатьев Может быть много. Например, если в результате сохранения произошло исключение, то наверное нужно как-то информаировать пользователя, что операция не удалась? И что подразумевается под "среднего приложения" ? А если большое приложение?

Comment: Вот в этом-то всё и дело. Если у тебя много одинакового кода - значит ты что-то делаешь не так.

Comment: @Ипатьев ну почему одинакового? Много кода и много разной логики, однако, так или иначе, с возможными исключениями. Ну или предположим даже то же сохранение, оно же может выполняться после блоков с какой-то бизнес логикой. Соответственно это всё будет реализовано в своей сущности. Если бы операция была бы одинаковой на всё - понятно, можно делать базовые классы или абстрактные и т.д., а когда что-то привязано к конкретной сущности и конкретной логике - это уже другое

Comment: При чем здесь абстрактные классы? Какая ещё разная логика? Ты нить обсуждения не потерял? "логирования и информирования пользователя" - что здесь "разное"?

Comment: Тебе надо для начала понять разницу между фатальными ошибками, и всеми другими. Если у тебя упала база, то никакой "пустой массив" при этом не возвращают. В этом случае надо писать "извините, что-то пошло не так". А для этого трай кетч на каждый чих, как у тебя в вопросе, писать не нужно.

Answer (score 5):

Проблема с блоками try catch в учебниках в том, что они все высосаны из пальца. И никогда не применяются в таких ситуациях в реальной жизни.

Автору учебника так проще, ему надо как-то показать пример обработки исключения. Но на самом деле try catch применяется гораздо реже, чем можно подумать, читая учебники.

Во-первых, и в самых главных: никакой "*обработки ошибки в виде её логирования и информирования пользователя, что "Извините, но что-то пошло не так*" в коде быть, разумеется не должно. Решение о том, что именно делать в случае неисправимой ошибки, должно приниматься централизованно, **на уровне приложения**. А не так, что каждый кусок кода делает это по-своему.

Для "информирования и логирования" должен быть **единый обработчик фатальных ошибок**, ну или на крайний случай - один глобальный тry catch, который оборачивает точку входа. Который и занимается тем, что обрабатывает ошибку в зависимости от настроек окружения. И прекрасно покажет пользователю текст "Что-то пошло не так". Только в этом случае данный текст мы пишем в одном месте, а не 100500 раз в каждом try catch. Логично же?

Не говоря уже о том, что одним росчерком пера, одной переменной в коде, мы можем поменять обработку ошибок с вывода фразы "Что-то пошло не так" на вывод подробной отладочной информации, например с использованием [whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) что будет очень удобно при разработке на локальном компьютере. Всё это преимущества централизованной обработки ошибок.

Таким образом мы избавляемся от 90% вызовов try catch в коде. В частности, всех примеров try catch приведенных в вопросе.

Дальше у нас остаются реальные случаи применения  try-catch - то есть точечная обработка не фатальных ошибок. Но придумать такой случай искусственно очень сложно. Но можно.

- вызов не критичного для работы приложения модуля
- обработка изображений в цикле и пропуск битых
- транзакции (хотя скажем в пхп их тоже заворачивать в try catch не обязательно)
- реконнект к БД в случае некоторых ошибок
- обращение к внешнему API и опять же, обработка некоторых ошибок. Например, если токен просрочен, то надо запросить новый. Вот это как раз работа для try-catch
- или вот например реализация нескольких попыток того же действия, как в [retry](https://github.com/igorw/retry/blob/master/src/retry.php)

Но это всё частные случаи, которые редко встречаются в контроллерах.

Случай, который действительно может встретиться в контроллере - это исключения, связанные с управлением ходом выполнения. Например у нас есть метод, который сохраняет данные в БД, и он может выкинуть ошибку валидации. Эту ошибку имеет смысл поймать при вызове сервиса в контроллере, и донести до пользователя. То есть при вызове метода ловим **конкретно эту ошибку валидации** и превращаем её в ответ для пользователя.

Comment: Интересные мысли. Не знаю почему минусы. Ещё почитаю поразмышляю

Comment: Вот пример [готовой реализации для РНР](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#code). Собственно, во всех современных фреймворках она и применяется. В контроллерах (и в моделях) практически никогда не пишется try catch поскольку в 90% обработка ошибки абсолютно одинаковая и логично написать её в одном месте

Comment: @Ипатьев скажите, а почему в php транзакции не обязательно оборачивать в try/catch?

Comment: @АнтонМеталлов потому что РНР умирает после завершения работы, а умирая - закрывает соединение с БД. А при закрытии соединения mysql автоматом откатывает все начатые в нем транзакции. Так что в теории оборачивать только для того чтобы сделать rollback  - не нужно. Но обычно все пишут - для собственного спокойствия :)

Comment: @Ипатьев скажите пожалуйтста. получается, что в коде где нужна транзация с коммитом/откатом - нужно **обязательно начинать транзакцию** а потом уже ничего не оборачивать и не делать роллбэков? Транзакцию нужно в любом случае начать программно, правильно? Например через yii `$connection->beginTransaction();`  и всё, так?

Comment: @СергейО. я не понял вопроса. в коде, где нужна транзакция, её надо начать, да. если транзакцию не начать, то её не будет

Answer (score -3):

Вам нужно передавать в delete ещё какой-то объект, в который вы и будете записывать ответ, например класс Status:

```
public class Status
{
    public bool success;
    public Exception ex;
}

public void delete(Page page, Status status)
{
    try
    {
        deletePageAndAllReferences(page);
        status.success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logError(e);
        status.success = false;
        status.ex = e;
    }
}
```

Перед вызовом delete вы создаёте объект в котором будет содержаться результат выполнения функции и информация об ошибке, можете городить что угодно в данном классе.

PS Нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы мешать try/catch с кодом, данную конструкцию хорошо использовать, когда несколько catch с разными Exception'ами или для более сложного функционала с дополнительными вызовами, например в Status можно записать event/delegate, тот-же logger, и можно в случае ошибки вызывать динамически записанные функции.
В результате и ваши принципы сохраняются, и компактность кода, и дополнительный функционал.

Comment: ага, и всю эту бороду писать на каждый вызов deletePageAndAllReferences(). Вот это я называю программированием.

Comment: Причём тут конкретно delete? Такой пример может быть в каком угодно контексте. А если у нас приложение, работающее на фоне, которое общается с каким-то устройством? Прерывать работу бесконечного цикла и завершать программу? Или плевать в лицо пользователю экзепшнами, которые пользователь не просил?

Comment: При том что это написано в ответе. А про "приложение на фоне" в ответе не написано. А пользователь тут вообще не при чем.

Comment: Все варианты не распишешь. Можно наверное было предположить что там не только вызов одиночной функции может быть или нет!?

Comment: Все варианты не распишешь, и при этом ты расписал вариант, который вообще не нужен. Очень логично :)

Comment: Использовал предоставленный, у вас вообще нет никакого варианта контроля на основе предложенного кода.

Comment: Нету потому что он и не нужен :))) Учитесь программировать. Это **очень сильно** сокращает количество кода.

Comment: Ещё раз, представьте, что вместо delete какой-нибудь ReadSCPacket и всё это в бесконечном цикле, который прерывать нельзя, это уже верхний уровень, который нужно оборачивать. Какие варианты? Сильнее углубляться и плодить try/catch? Или завершать то, что должно работать без остановки? Так-же как и у автора, это может быть верхний уровень.

Comment: Ещё раз. Если это какой-нибудь ReadSCPacket и всё это в бесконечном цикле, то всё это не имеет отношения к коду, который написан у автора вопроса. И если так хочется порассуждать про пакеты и циклы, то делать это надо не в комментариях, а в ответе. И не в виде рекомендации для общего случая, а поясняя что такой код используется в виде исключения, для совсем других случаев чем те, которые описаны в вопросе

Comment: И что мешает использовать мой вариант как универсальный, как для цикла - так и для остального? Из коробки экзепшен можно достать и заново выкинуть. И вообще по хорошему нужно перехватывать ошибки чаще, т.к. есть не мало операций, которые надо откатывать в случае неудачи.

Comment: Ты уж определись - "использовать мой универсальный" или "немало операций, которые надо откатывать". Смотри, ты написал искусственный, никому не нужный код, который решает несуществующую проблему. Какой вообще смысл в таком ответе? Зачем вообще высасывать ответы из пальца? У меня ответ из практики, я сам пользуюсь тем подходом, который описал. А у тебя что? Какой ещё класс "статус"? Что с ним делать? В реальности, я имею в виду

Comment: Я минимизировал тот код, которым сам пользуюсь, конечно в рабочей задаче передаваемой инфы намного больше. Классы называться могут как угодно. Выйдите за пределы конкретики и посмотрите на ситуацию в общем, в теме вопроса спрашивалось именно это.

Comment: если не учитывать то, что мне решение не нравиться, по факту, вы в методе `delete` возвращаете `Exception`, т.к. `class Status` — это nullable паттерн. и тут напрашивается вопрос: зачем вводили систему исключений? может, чтобы не возвращать коды ошибок/указатели на структуру ошибки, как в C?

Comment: @return Лично я использую такой подход, чтобы можно было передавать задачу (класс содержащий команду delete) в очереди на выполнение в других потоках и в качестве микро-отчёта получить ответ (Status), заранее поместив его в список выполняемых и выполненных задач. Для примера Status сильно упрощён. Вдобавок это очень полезно (имхо) при работе через API и при сериализации. А поток, реально обрабатывающий задачу сам обновляет Status, и там где нужно видеть "прогресс" - Status уже есть. Тут 4в1: мониторинг, исключения, логи, ответ в API с сериализацией.

Comment: @return У меня самописный API базируется на подобном подходе и работает без нареканий уже больше года. А если где-то null вылезет, то try-catch на несколько уровней выше что в одном потоке, что в другом его успешно перехватит. Да и вопрос больше уже к тому, кто по-умолчанию в методы null'ы кидает.

Comment: 1) в вопросе нет потоков и, как следствие, мониторинга 2) try-catch и логгирование идут бок о бок. если вы посматривали на код .NET Core/5, то замечали, что [явный] try-finally в 90% случаев используется для логгирования 3) ответ API можно обернуть в метод-адаптер, адаптирующий вид выдаваемой ошибки 4) согласен, что в .NET очень слабая система обработки ошибок. тут даже option и either нет, очень полезные монады для любого языка программирования

Comment: @return согласен, в вопросе нет потоков, но я не могу представить ни одну сложную систему/программу без мониторинга (пусть даже и без API). Тем не менее пусть лучше даже без потоков, иметь какой-нибудь контейнер, через который можно отслеживать статус выполнения задачи постфактум (после выполнения или при ошибке), с необходимыми параметрами задачи (речь про вариант класса Status с большим числом полей). И при этом при ошибке иметь готовый микро-отчёт, который можно куда-то выплюнуть (лог), чем собирать причины сбоя по кусочкам. Если кратко - для меня это универсальный и беспроблемный подход.

Comment: @return главная "фишка" в том, что в случае перехвата исключения - не нужно дальше тянуть цепь вызовов, и зарываться в разбор "что пошло не так, и что мы на ноль поделили" плодя лапшу, а можно вернуться назад и постфактум централизованно сообщить о проблеме на тот уровень, с которого произошёл вызов, чем мучаться доставать Exception'ы из семи кругов ада.

Comment: мне кажется `throw` — самый простой способ передачи исключения "пузырьком" и его централизованной обработки. если нужно больше полей, создайте свой класс исключения. просто ваш метод по умолчанию хуже, т.к., во-первых, не является родным для .NET, во-вторых, не распространён. так с любым не родным решением. и я пока не вижу преймуществ вашего метода над традиционным `throw`. дайте пример реального кода или ссылку на github, может так мне будет проще понять